# Irregular print statements in multiple producer consumer program

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, producer-consumer

Shared queue is one. Producers and Consumers are two, each.

Below is the output, and I have pasted the program after that:

**My problem is that the print statement `qDebug () << "\nConsumer: " << tId;`, is at the top still it didn't print first. I want to understand why.**

---

```
Producer  140588830992128  couldn't push any data since queue was already full. Length of queue is:  10
Removed by thread Consumer:  140588814206720 , Length of queue is:  9
Removed by thread Consumer:  140588814206720 , Length of queue is:  8
Removed by thread Consumer:  140588814206720 , Length of queue is:  7
Removed by thread Consumer:  140588814206720 , Length of queue is:  6
Removed by thread Consumer:  140588814206720 , Length of queue is:  5
Consumer:  140588814206720
Removed by thread Consumer:  140588814206720 , Length of queue is:  4
Removed by thread Consumer:  140588814206720 , Length of queue is:  3
Removed by thread Consumer:  140588814206720 , Length of queue is:  2
Consumer:  140588814206720
Removed by thread Consumer:  140588814206720 , Length of queue is:  1
Consumer:  140588814206720
Removed by thread Consumer:  140588814206720 , Length of queue is:  0
```

---

**Here is the program that I wrote:**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <QDebug>

pthread_mutex_t mutexVariable     = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t  conditionVariable = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

int numberOfActiveProducers;
int numberOfActiveConsumers;

QList <int> sharedQueue;
/*
 * `sharedQueue`'s size is assumed to be 10 ATM.
 * `sharedQueue` is supposed to be shared among two threads.
 * Producer threads will put the 1's in it, and Consumer threads will remove the 1's.
 * Assumption: `sharedQueue` can contain only 10 elements at a time.
 */

int sizeOfSharedQueue;

//  This function is run by the `Producer` threads.
void *producerThreadFunction (void *arg) {
    Q_UNUSED (arg);

    while (1) {
        pthread_t tId = pthread_self();
        qDebug () << "\nProducer: " << tId;

        pthread_mutex_lock (&mutexVariable);

        if (sharedQueue.length () < 10) {
            sharedQueue.push_back (1);
            qDebug () << "\nPushed by Producer " << tId << ": " << "Length of queue is: " << sharedQueue.length ();
        }
        else {
            qDebug () << "\nProducer " << tId << " has no work to do since quque is full, and is now in waiting mode. Length of queue is: " << sharedQueue.length ();
            pthread_cond_wait (&conditionVariable, &mutexVariable);
        }

        pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutexVariable);
    }

    return NULL;
}

//  This function is run by the `Consumer` threads.
void *consumerThreadFunction (void *arg) {
    Q_UNUSED (arg);

    while (1) {
        pthread_t tId = pthread_self ();
        qDebug () << "\nConsumer: " << tId;

        pthread_mutex_lock (&mutexVariable);

        if (sharedQueue.length () > 0) {
            for (int u = 0; u < sharedQueue.length (); u++) {
                sharedQueue.pop_front ();
                qDebug () << "\nRemoved by thread Consumer: " << tId << ", Length of queue is: " << sharedQueue.length ();
            }
        }
        else {
            pthread_cond_signal (&conditionVariable);
            qDebug () << "\nSignal issued by thread Consumer: " << tId << ", Length of queue is: " << sharedQueue.length ();
        }

        pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutexVariable);
    }   
    return NULL;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    numberOfActiveProducers = 2;
    numberOfActiveConsumers = 2;
    sizeOfSharedQueue       = 10;

    // Producer threads creation
    pthread_t producerA;
    pthread_t producerB;

    if (pthread_create (&producerA, NULL, producerThreadFunction, NULL)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error creating thread Producer A\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (pthread_create (&producerB, NULL, producerThreadFunction, NULL)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error creating thread Producer B\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Consumer threads creation
    pthread_t consumerA;
    pthread_t consumerB;

    if (pthread_create (&consumerA, NULL, consumerThreadFunction, NULL)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error creating thread Consumer A\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (pthread_create (&consumerB, NULL, consumerThreadFunction, NULL)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error creating thread Consumer B\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Joining every thread
    if (pthread_join (producerA, NULL)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error joining thread Producer A\n");
        return 2;
    }

    if (pthread_join (producerB, NULL)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error joining thread Producer B\n");
        return 2;
    }

    if (pthread_join (consumerB, NULL)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error joining thread Consumer B\n");
        return 2;
    }

    if (pthread_join (consumerA, NULL)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error joining thread Consumer A\n");
        return 2;
    }

    QApplication a (argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show ();

    return a.exec ();
}
```

Added the screenshot with `std::cerr`. No difference in output:

[image]

Comment: Why did you tag this C? You appear to be writing Qt C++.

Comment: I don't know what `qDebug()` does. Is it thread-safe? What happens if you replace it with `cout<< ... << endl;`?

Comment: The output you provide does not match the program you quote there. Further, many of the pthread calls are not checked for any errors. That said, why don't you use C++ threads?

Comment: According to their [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-reentrancy.html), if not explicitly stated to be thread-safe, then a function is not. And [qDebug()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html) doesn't say anything about it. So it's thread-unsafe. So what probably happens is that one call overwrites the previous call's value as it might be using a static buffer before being printed. I think, as a result of this, you have undefined behaviour.

Comment: @I3x I cannot use std::cout. I tried it today but nothing was printed. Facility with qDebug () is that it prints the value then and there itself. Specially while programming QML, qDebug is very necessary since cout prints only at the end of the program. BTW, this time, when I stopped the program, it didn't print anything at all. This is exactly what I tried: `while (1) {
        pthread_t tId = pthread_self (); //qDebug () << "\nConsumer: " << tId;
        std::cout <<"\nConsumerjjj: ";`

Comment: @I3x besides the above comment, see the new screenshot with std::cerr as was suggested in the below answer.

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius Well `qDebug()` is not thread-safe. So you just can't use it. `cout` might be buffering the output. Call `cout.flush();` after cout calls.

Comment: @I3x qDebug was commented in the code in the above comment. Will try flush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my system I do see the output you expect, starting with:

```
Producer:  0x700000081000 
Consumer:  0x700000187000 
Producer:  0x700000104000 
Consumer:  0x70000020a000
```

But this is just luck, because it seems that qDebug() is not guaranteed to be thread-safe.  One solution might be to only do logging while you hold the mutex.  Or use a different logging facility.  Note that writing to `std::cerr` is thread-safe, but you may end up with interleaving if you write multiple tokens using `<<`.  So you can format your log lines first, and write them "atomically" via `std::cerr.write()`.

Comment: see the screenshot with std::cerr in the question. What to do now?

Comment: Well I'm not sure, this doesn't make a lot of sense to me.